# Append separate requests from endpoint X and endpoint Y into a single React Query

Tags: react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm working with React Query and my backend provides two relevant endpoints that I consume

- `/records/` -> this lists all records, paginated
- `/records/unowned` -> this lists all the records which are not linked to an owner, also paginated

For my purposes, I would like to request these two endpoints at different times but dump the responses from both into one big bucket in the Query Cache, presumably under a single query key so that I can do `queryClient.getQueryData(["records"])` and see every record that I have fetched already.

If I write my queries with a single query key, though, i'll overwrite the first request with the data from the second or use data from the first request if it isn't stale and never make the second request.

Is there a way I can use a second query and add its contents to the first?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this by using the `useQuery` hook's enabled option to conditionally fetch the second query based on the first one's data.

```js
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

const fetchRecords = async () => {
  const recordsResponse = await fetch('/records/');
  const records = await recordsResponse.json();
  const unownedRecordsResponse = await fetch('/records/unowned');
  const unownedRecords = await unownedRecordsResponse.json();

  return [...records, ...unownedRecords];
};


const useRecords = () => {
  return useQuery('records', fetchRecords);
};
```

By default, the `useQuery` hook will only fetch the data once and then cache it. If you want to refetch the data when the component mounts, you can pass the enabled option as true to the useQuery hook:

```js
const { data, isLoading, error } = useRecords({ enabled: true });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited in more detail that I want to be able to request these endpoints individually and at different times, rather than all at once

Answer (score 0):

I would keep them in separate cache entries, e.g.

`['records', 'all']` and `['records', 'unowned']`

and then access it imperatively with

`queryClient.getQueriesData['records']` which will give you both.

In a component, you can use the `useQueries` hook to combine both results.

Comment: Thank you! You'd do this even though `unowned` is a subset of `all`?

Comment: yes. it's the same as `['todos', 'all']` vs. `['todos', { filter: { done: true }}]`. Different query params require different cache entries